# add char **tokens incrementally to char *token in C

Tags: c, char

I tried many solution for this issue, but none worked properly!

I want to copy value of char** array to a variable of type char*.

```
char *line;
char **tokens = malloc(....);
```

So, I tried the following:

```
for(i=0; i < sizeof(tokens); i++)
    strncpy(line, tokens[i], strlen(line));
```

Or

```
for(i=0; i < sizeof(tokens); i++)
    strncat(line, tokens[i]);
```

Or

```
for(i=0; i < sizeof(tokens); i++)
    memcpy(line, tokens[i], strlen(line));
```

My understanding is that tokens[i] would be of type char*, but what I couldn't understand if the error I'm getting.

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If these ways won't work, how can I do the copying?

Any hints?

```
char *removesubString(char *path, char **args){
        char *dir;
        int COUNT;
        COUNT = 100;
        char **dirs = malloc(sizeof(char*)*COUNT);
    int i, position;
    for (i = 2; i < sizeof(args); i++) {
        if(args[i] == NULL){
            break;
            }
        dir = strtok(path, PATH_DELIM);
        position = 0;
        while (dir != NULL) {
            if(strcmp(dir, args[i]) == 0){
                dir = strtok(NULL, PATH_DELIM);
                continue;
            }
            dirs[position] = dir;
            position++;
            dir = strtok(NULL, PATH_DELIM);
        }//end of while
        dirs[position] = NULL;
    }//end of for
    char *line;
    line = "";
    for (i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            strncpy(line, dirs[i], strlen(dirs[i]));
    }
    return line;
}
```

Comment: You need to divide `sizeof(tokens)` by `sizeof(char*)` to find out how many elements it can hold, but you should have known that when you allocated it with `malloc()` anyway. How did you allocate `line`?

Comment: @meramees  It is not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to concatenate in line all strings stored in tokens?

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst I allocate it this way tokens = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(line));

Comment: @VladfromMoscow yes exactly

Comment: @meramees: That can't be right. It should be `sizeof(char*)` times the *number* of tokens.

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst but I don't know the number of tokens at the very beginning, can it be any large number?

Comment: Yes you can make it very large. But when you allocate `tokens`, it just gives you space for each of its entries' *pointer*. You need to also allocate each entry when you populate it with tokens. Can you show the code you use to put the tokens into it?

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst editted the question above to show the whole code I'm writing

Comment: @meramees Show a minimal program that demonstartes the problem. From your post it is not clear how tokens were gotten and how line is initialized.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow already did that

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst can you provide a line of code of what you trying to say, please?

Comment: I believe `removesubstring()` is doomed from the start.  Your lack of proper indentation hides that you're calling `strtok()` on the same string in a loop -- `strtok()` modifies `path` the first time through the `for` loop so subsequent iterations have a damaged string to work with.  You probably need to copy the string you sacrifice to `strtok()`.  If you could provide your documentation for the `removesubstring()` function someone here might be able to help you sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue that pops up about your code is that you're wrong with the boundaries:

```
char *line;
char **tokens = malloc(TOKENS_ARRAY_SIZE);
```

when you do:

```
for(i=0; i < sizeof(tokens); i++) {
   …
}
```

it's not returning the size of the allocated memory, but the allocated memory for the `tokens` pointer itself. From the [sizeof manpage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof):

> *Returns the size, in bytes, of the object representation of type*

It happens that when you do `sizeof` on a static matrix, it will return the size of the matrix because that's the amount of allocated memory for it. But for a dynamically allocated matrix, it will only return the size of the pointer, i.e. if you do:

```
char array_static[42];
char* array_dyn = malloc(sizeof(char)*42);
printf("sizeof(array_static) = %d\n", sizeof(array_static));
printf("sizeof(array_dyn) = %d\n", sizeof(array_dyn));
```

it will return:

```
sizeof(array_static) = 42
sizeof(array_dyn) = 8
```

so if the number of items within your dynamic array is less than the returned size of the array's pointer, you'll overflow and you'll get a segfault.

So the right way to handle your situation, is to keep the length of the dynamic array in another variable, update it as you're setting up the size of the allocated memory, and then use that value for iterations.

```
int tokens_length = 42;
char *line;
char **tokens = malloc(sizeof(char*)*tokens_length);

for(i=0; i < sizeof(tokens_length); i++) {
    …
}
```

so in your case, you should be doing:

```
// keep somewhere the number of directories that you *can* allocate
int nb_dirs = 100;
char **dirs = malloc(sizeof(char*) * nb_dirs);

…

// keep a pointer on how many directories you've added
int position = 0;
while (dir != NULL) {
    …
    position++;
    // fail loudly if you're adding more directories than you've allocated
    // or you might use realloc() to extend the array's length
    if (position >= nb_dirs) {
        printf("ERROR! Too many directories!");
        // RETURN WITH ERROR!
    }
    …
}
// here you iterate over all the directories you've added
for(i = 0; i <= position; i++){
    // here you can do stuff with dirs, and copy only the length of the dirs element
    strncpy(<TARGET>, dirs[i], strlen(dirs[i]);
}
```

Then there's another issue you should think about: in your loop, you're modifying `path`, given as an argument, where you're `strcpy()`ing dirs into:

```
strncpy(path, dirs[i], <LENGTH>);
```

But that makes little sense, whatever you're trying to do is not what you've written.

Here, considering that the size argument is correctly set, you'd be copying each item of the `dirs` array into the same variable. So you'd end up having *always* the last value of the `dirs` array referenced at the path pointer.

But the issue is that you only have the path pointer, but you know little about how it has been allocated when it's been given to the function. How has it been allocated, and how much memory was allocated? What "useful" size is it (though that one can be guessed with `strlen()`)?

Oh, and finally, don't forget to `free()` your allocations once you're done with them. Do not leak memory, that's rude! ☺

---

edit:

ok, here are stuff I can see that are wrong, and some comments about it:

```
char *removesubString(char *path, char **args){
    char *dir;
    int COUNT = 100;
    char **dirs = malloc(sizeof(char*)*COUNT);
    int i, position;

    /* for both XXX marks below:
     *
     * below, sizeof(args) will return the size of the pointer
     * not the number of items it contains. You *NEED* to pass
     * a "int argc" as parameter to your function, that gives
     * the numbers of items in the array.
     * Think about why you have argc in the main() function construct:
     *      int main(int argc, const char** argv)
     * _OR_ if the args array of strings is _ALWAYS_ terminated
     * by a NULL item, then you should do: */
    // int i = 0;
    // while(args[i] != NULL) {
    //     /* do stuff */
    //     ++i;
    // }

    for (i = 2; i < sizeof(args) /* XXX */; i++) {
        if(args[i] == NULL){ /* XXX */
            break;
        }
        dir = strtok(path, PATH_DELIM);
        position = 0;
        while (dir != NULL) {
            if(strcmp(dir, args[i]) == 0){
                dir = strtok(NULL, PATH_DELIM);
                continue;
            }
            /* because within the function you have no guarantee
             * on the number of tokens within path, if you have
             * more than 100 tokens, you will overflow the dirs array.
             * a good idea would be to test whether position is bigger
             * than or equal to COUNT, and if it is use realloc to
             * extend dirs */

            dirs[position] = dir;
            position++;

            dir = strtok(NULL, PATH_DELIM);

            /* you could avoid having twice the former line 
             * and instead make your loop body being: */
            // while (dir != NULL) {
            //     if(strcmp(dir, args[i]) != 0){
            //         /* TODO: check position vs COUNT and realloc dirs if necessary */
            //         dirs[position] = dir;
            //         ++position;
            //     }
            //     dir = strtok(NULL, PATH_DELIM);
            // }
        }
        dirs[position] = NULL;
    }
    char *line;
    line = ""; /* ← here you allocate line with a string of length 1 */
    for (i = 0; i < position; i++) {
        // so here, you'll write up to the number of characters 
        // within dirs[i], into a string of length one.
        strncpy(line, dirs[i], strlen(dirs[i]));
    }
    /* And even if it was working you'd be assigning the line 
     * variable to a new value at each iteration, ending up doing
     * something equivalent to the following line, but with "position"
     * numbers of iterations: */
    // strncpy(line, dirs[position-1], strlen(dirs[position-1]));

    /* Don't forget to free the instances you've allocated dynamically
     * before leaving the function: */
    // free(dirs);

    /* And finally there's another issue here, you're returning
     * a variable that has been statically allocated above, so that
     * when you'll try to use the pointed instance in the calling
     * context, that variable won't exist anymore. */
    return line;
}
```

---

HTH

Comment: Million thanks for your detailed answer, 
I tried what what have mentioned here and edited my code as required, Can you look at my edited version of the code and highlight the lines where I miss any of your points, please?

Comment: Basically, there's not one error, but a number of errors that will lead to segfaults and buffer overflows. Sadly, for most of them, the compiler cannot catch them, but you can use a static analyzer tool to try to spot them. Though, a better way is to correctly think your code so you wouldn't even write that can of errors in the first place.